# Formular RegEx que muestre un texto que está dentro de un paréntesis

Tags: python, regex

Necesito un RegEx para dejar solamente lo que se encuentra entré los corchetes [ ], este es un ejemplo del texto:

`HM-WP-MB-22NOV10-03[24MO+36MO+6YE+12YE RED] MPD R00`

`HM-WP HC-UUI MAY20 [24M+36M+6Y+12U]`

Debe entregar para este ejemplo lo siguiente:

`[24MO+36MO+6YE+12YE RED]`

`[24M+36M+6Y+12U]`

Solo sirve lo que está en el interior de los  [ ]

Comment: Prueba con este, creo que sí te servirá `/\[[\w\+\s]+\]/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para **extraer el texto que está entre corchetes**, utiliza la expresión regular:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

De esta forma, por ejemplo:

```
import re

a_string = "HM-WP-MB-22NOV10-03[24MO+36MO+6YE+12YE RED] MPD R00"
result = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]", a_string)
print('[' + result.group(1) + ']')
```

Salida:

```
[24MO+36MO+6YE+12YE RED]
```

Explicación:

- `\[` : `[` es un caracter especial y necesita la secuencia de escape `\` para que se pueda encontrar literalmente.
- `(.*?)` : coincide cualquier caracter. Puedes cambiarlo por una expresión distinta para que coincidan solamente letras, números, etc.
- `\]` : `]` es un caracter especial, así que se trata igual que el primer `[`